# PHP - Close child window, refresh parent window, go to anchor

Tags: javascript, php

I have an `all_list.php` file from which I want to edit data. It's set up as a table with cells for the data. I have each of the cells set up as a pop-up windows to edit... as:

```
<td class="popup"><a href="edit_notes.php?id=' . $id . '" >' . $notes . '</a></td>
```

After I'm done editing my data in the `edit_notes.php` window, I want to close it, refresh the parent window, and go to an anchor in `all_list.php`.

I have a javascript at the end of `edit_notes.php` that can close the child window and refresh the parent:

```
<script language="javascript">
   window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
   if (window.opener.progressWindow) { window.opener.progressWindow.close() } window.close();
 </script>
```

… but I don't know how to tell it "once you're done refreshing, go to this anchor on the parent page".

I have tried using all iterations of the `header` syntax but all it does it reload the Parent table in the Child window.

Is there a way to tell PHP to do all three things:

1. Close the child window
2. Refresh the Parent window
3. Go to an anchor on the Parent page

Comment: `PHP` cannot modify the DOM, for that you need `js`

Comment: Is there a way to modify the javascript I've shown to do what I need to do?

Comment: take a look at `.parent()` and `.children()` functions.   `location.reload()` will refresh the parent window